# Creating a rating system for displaying rating stars in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, rating

I've a values something like this **1.25, 2.50, 3.75 or 4.00**:

I can loop on the integers like 1, 2, 3 or 4.

But how I can loop on 3.75?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3.75; i++)
{
    // my logic
}
```

### Updated:

The loop I needed as I'm creating a rating system and displaying the rating stars in loop. For example:

If 1.25 then star 1 and quarter (0.25) of star 2. Or if 4.75 then star 4 and last quarter (0.75) of star.

[image] 3.75/5

How I can display rating in stars?

Comment: If you iterate by 1.25, you should get 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5.0, right?

Comment: Yes but It can be change.

Comment: If the increment is going to change to something that cannot be represented precisely, e.g. 1.2 instead of 1.25, you have to be very careful of what you are doing.

Comment: See @dasblinkenlight 's answer and also read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @GeorgeVovos thanks I'll read it , did you see at **bounty description**.

Comment: I think you should update the question,which probably isn't about for loops(or even c#) but drawing a specific percent  of a star?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prepare 2 image files, one has 5 empty-stars and the other has 5 filled-stars, just like:
   [image][image]

   the 2 images must have same width and height, e.g. 400X70
2. place the filled-stars overlap on the empty-stars, then crop the filled-stars to a portion of the origin witdh the same as the Rating,

i.e. the crop div width = image_width / 5 * rating

e.g. With 3.5 Rating, width = 400 / 5 * 3.5 = 280

```html
  <html>
  <head><title>test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .container > * {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .container, .crop {
            height: 70px;
        }

        .crop {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiT2y.png" />
        <!-- the width could be calculated either at server or client side, or define in css -->
        <div class="crop" style="width:280px">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTi9e.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although generally it's not a good idea to loop on `double`, especially when you check for equality in the loop, in your case it's OK because your loop increment is can be represented precisely as a combination of powers of 2. Specifically, 1.25 is 2<sup>0</sup>+2<sup>-2</sup>.

```
for (double i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i+=1.25) {
    // my logic
}
```

Alternatively, you could loop on `int`, and multiply loop counter by 1.25:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++) {
    double val = 1.25 * i;
    //
}
```

> I'm creating a rating system and displaying the rating stars in loop.

You don't need a loop for this. If you have a number between 0 and 5, inclusive, representing the average, you need to know three things:

- How many "filled" stars to display,
- How big is the filled portion of of the partially-filled star, and
- How many "blank" stars to display.

You can find out the answers to these three questions using math:

- The number of "filled" stars is the integer portion of the number after truncation
- The fraction of the partially filled star is the decimal part of the number
- The number of "blank" stars is `5-ceil(n)`, where `ceil(n)` represents the "ceiling" of the number (i.e. the smallest `int` equal or higher than `n`).

Comment: should each time multiply with 1.25?

Comment: @Asif.Ali If you iterate on integers, then yes, you would need to multiply by 1.25 on each iteration. This is pretty cheap in terms of performance, though.

Comment: @Asif.Ali You don't need a loop for what you are doing. Please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Just use loop variable of type double:

```
for (double x = 1.25; x <= 4; x += 1.25)
{
    // Your logic
}
```

Comment: can I loop on `0.somthing`?

Comment: @Asif.Ali Yes, you can. Whether or not you'll see problems depends a great deal on the value of "something". If it's 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, etc., there would be no problem. If it is 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc., you need to be very careful with anything requiring equality checks. For example, adding up `0.1` ten times does not yield `1` when you use `double`s.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight actually I'm calculating average rating from 5 scale points, therefore I need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list of accepted values instead of iterating on float. If you don't want to manually edit known values, one way to generate them would be:

```
IEnumerable<float> CalculateBreakpoints(int min, int max, short unitPartitions)
{
    var fraction = 1f / unitPartitions;
    for (float i = min; i <= max; i += fraction)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

It's unlikely that in the wild you'll have ratings that exactly match your known values. You could try choosing known value closest to rating at hand or approach it some other way. Amazon for example shows closest value above actual rating. That could be done like this:

```
float MapRatingToBreakpoint(float rating, IEnumerable<float> breakpoints)
{
    var min = breakpoints.Min();
    var max = breakpoints.Max();

    if (rating < min || rating > max)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rating));
    }

    foreach (var point in breakpoints)
    {
        if (rating <= point)
        {
            rating = point;
            break;
        }
    }

    return rating;
}
```

Once you have a processed rating, to display stars on the front end this code would be able to choose what type of star to use:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    if (i <= Math.floor(rating)) {
        console.log("addFullStar()");
    }
    else if (i > Math.ceil(rating)) {
        console.log("addEmptyStar()");
    }
    else {
        fraction = rating - i + 1;
        console.log(`addPartialStar(fraction: ${fraction}`);
    }
}
```

At this point it's up to you to choose how you want to display each type of star. You could use a sprite with all the different stars and play with CSS classes like `<span class="star-0-25" />` to attach correct images. Another option for displaying a partial star could be to add full and empty star on top of each other, have empty star with hidden overflow, full star with visible overflow and adjust width of a parent tag.